# Process Builder: Update Name field in a Object

Tags: process-builder

I have created a process builder with the following properties.

Choose Object section:
Object: Communication_Method__c

Start the Process:
When a record is created or edited.

Criteria Section:
No criteria-just execute the actions!

Action section:

Update Records
Object: [Communication_Method__c]

Set Object Variables:
Field: Name 
Value: [Communication_Method__c].Contact__c

Update is working fine, but during insert I am getting "Name is a required field"

Can I not populate a field in the same object with a value of another field during insert using process builder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Triggers and Order of Execution document](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm): when saving from a standard Salesforce UI page, require field validation at the page or field definition level occurs at #2, while processes do not run until #14. So the field must be populated beforehand.

Unfortunately there isn't a way to specify a default value at the field definition level for the standard Name field, so I don't see a code-free way around this. If you were creating the Communication_Method__c through a quick action you could use a predefined value, but that won't work for standard new/edit pages.

Answer (score 0):

shannonsans answer is good.I had already facing this issue because validation rules will fire first in Sales force order of execution.

My suggestion is if name is a custom field you can remove required in layout level access.But if it is a standard field you can go to create a custom visual force page. @Arup Sarkar